# Is it possible to use MMS to stream Internet radio in Android?

Tags: android, stream, mms

Is possible to play an Internet radio stream in Android? And since most of the Internet radios use MMS to stream their content is *that* possible using Android?

Comment: How to play SHOUTcast?http://stackoverflow.com/a/8833346/265167

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html) about audio, video and streaming on Android.

This simple examples was extracted from this page. It creates an instance of media player, set the data source (stream location) and starts the communication.

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(PATH_TO_FILE);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick answer, 
pghilardi: are you sure that using MediaPlayer android can stream mms? because I have read that MediaPlayer doesn't support mms streaming.
Sanoj,loginx: thanks for the reference but I would like to know the way to stream and if like pghilardi said it is possible to stream using an standard android class and not to know if there is an application to listen to music to.
regards maxsap

Comment: I think that this tutorial could help you: http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2009/12/27/android-streaming-mediaplayer-tutorial-updated-to-v1-5-cupcake/

But i don't understand why the down votes to my answer. =P

Comment: Android's default MediaPlayer does not support the mms protocol. Only http and rdsp! a possible alternative for this would be the use of the  Vitamio library, http://vov.io/vitamio/, like someone mentioned in a similar thread

Answer (score 0):

I use an app called "Cherry Rplayer" for radio streaming on my Android phone. It allows you to stream to custom stations as well as pick anything from the built-in Shoutcast and Icecast directory browsers. You can also see the other apps from the developers, they have apps for custom mms streams, etc...