# Android MediaPlayer works fine in Custom audio Streaming application up to Android 2.1 but not in higher versions

Tags: android, audio, audio-streaming, android-mediaplayer, shoutcast

**EDIT:**

[Android 2.2 MediaPlayer is working fine with one SHOUTcast URL but not with the other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681550/android-2-2-mediaplayer-is-working-fine-with-one-shoutcast-url-but-not-with-the)

I need to play audio files from external URLs(shoutcast stream). Currently the audio files are downloaded incrementally & are played as soon as we get enough audio in phone local temporary storage. i am using the [StreamingMediaPlayer class](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/App/ijoker/cn/edu/xmu/software/streamradio/media/StreamingMediaPlayer.java.htm).

Check this piece of code:

```
    private MediaPlayer createMediaPlayer(File mediaFile)
            throws IOException {
        MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        //example of mediaFile =/data/data/package/cache/playingMedia0.dat
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mediaFile);
        mPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
        mPlayer.prepare();
        return mPlayer;
    }
```

**Current status:**

1- It works fine from Android 1.6 to 2.1 but not in the higher versions like Android 2.2.

2- The "mPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD())" is the line which throws the error.

3- The error is "Unable to to create media player"

**Other Solution tried:**

I tried below alternate solution but nothing worked so far.

[Android 2.2 MediaPlayer is working fine with one SHOUTcast URL but not with the other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681550/android-2-2-mediaplayer-is-working-fine-with-one-shoutcast-url-but-not-with-the)

**What i am looking for?**

My goal is to have a peace of code which can work on Android 2.1 & higher.

**This issue is also discussed here:**

1- [Inconsistent 2.2 Media Player Behavior](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9787)

2- [android code for streaming shoutcast stream breaks in 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4392663/265167)

3- This issue is also discussed in a lot of questions on this site, but i found the answer no where.

4- [markmail.org](http://markmail.org/message/oztg7eb2entfdu3i)

**LogCat trace:**

```
Unable to to create media player
Error copying buffered conent.
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.ms.iradio.StreamingMediaPlayer.startMediaPlayer(StreamingMediaPlayer.java:251)
com.ms.iradio.StreamingMediaPlayer.access$2(StreamingMediaPlayer.java:221)
com.ms.iradio.StreamingMediaPlayer$2.run(StreamingMediaPlayer.java:204)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Perhaps this link will answer your question, and if not, please post a trace for the error you get: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834548/android-code-for-streaming-shoutcast-stream-breaks-in-2-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `StreamingMediaPlayer` class is using a double-buffering technique to get around limitations in pre-1.2 releases of Android. All production releases of Android OS have included a MediaPlayer that supports streaming media(1). I would recommend doing that rather than using this double-buffering technique to get around the problem.

Android OS 2.2 replaced the old media player code with the FrightCast player which probably is acting differently in this case.

The line numbers in your stack trace don't map to the file you link to, so I assume there's a different version that you're actually using. I'm going to guess that that `NullPointerException` is being reported by `MediaPlayer` but neither the `FileInputStream` nor the returned `FileDescriptor` can be `null`.

(1) Prior to version 2.2 the media player wouldn't recognize ShoutCast streams with an "ICY/1.1" version header in the response. By creating a proxy that replaces this with "HTTP/1.1" you can resolve that. See the [StreamProxy class here](http://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/source/browse/Npr/src/org/npr/android/news/StreamProxy.java) for an example.

Comment: 1- I am using StreamingMediaPlayer only minor changes has been made to it.
2- npr StreamProxy class requires a lot of other classes (npr news for example), i have already tried it to use it but could not succeed to do it correctly.

Comment: Hmm... the stack trace shows line 251 in #startMediaPlayer but in the linked source that line is in #transferBufferToMediaPlayer. Also, StreamProxy from the NPR source requires nothing from the NPR source, but lots of stuff included in Android source. [See here](http://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/source/browse/Npr/src/org/npr/android/news/PlaybackService.java#347) for an implementation example or [the test](http://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/source/browse/Npr_Test/src/org/npr/android/news/StreamProxyTest.java) case.

Comment: Great thanks. i will try it on Monday. Please also check this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681550/android-2-2-mediaplayer-is-working-fine-with-one-shoutcast-url-but-not-with-the

Comment: @jwadsack help me at this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264225/andriod-shoutcast-internet-radio-filenotfoundexception

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that content type "audio/aacp" streaming is not supported directly. Some decoding libraries can be used to play "aacp", please see the solution below:

[Freeware Advanced Audio (AAC) Decoder for Android](http://code.google.com/p/aacplayer-android/)

[How to use this library?](http://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/source/browse/trunk/player/src/com/spoledge/aacplay/AACPlayerActivity.java)

**[Consider legal issues while using it](http://vaclavb.blogspot.com/2010/06/raw-aac-player-for-android.html).**

> [T]he project http://code.google.com/p/aacplayer-android/ is licensed
>   under GPL, so you can create commercial apps  on top of it, but you
>   need to fullfill the GPL - mainly it means to publish your code as
>   well.   If you use the second project
>   http://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/ , then you do not need to
>   publish your   code (the library is licensed under LGPL).

Comment: help me at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264225/andriod-shoutcast-internet-radio-filenotfoundexception

Answer (score 1):

i am using this code and run 2.2 to upper version for streaming downloaded.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class StreamingMediaPlayer {
private static final int INTIAL_KB_BUFFER =  96*10;//assume 96kbps*10secs/8bits per    byte

private TextView textStreamed;

private ImageButton playButton;

private ProgressBar progressBar;
ProgressBar pb;
int audiofiletime=0;
private long mediaLengthInSeconds;
private int totalKbRead = 0;
int totalsize=0;
int numread;
int totalBytesRead = 0;
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private File downloadingMediaFile; 
private boolean isInterrupted;
private Context context;
private int counter = 0;

public StreamingMediaPlayer(Context  context,TextView textStreamed, ImageButton playButton, Button  streamButton,ProgressBar progressBar,ProgressBar pb) 
{
    this.context = context;
    this.textStreamed = textStreamed;
    this.playButton = playButton;
    this.progressBar = progressBar;
    this.pb=pb;
}

/**  
 * Progressivly download the media to a temporary location and update the MediaPlayer as new content becomes available.
 */  
public void startStreaming(final String mediaUrl) throws IOException {


    //this.mediaLengthInSeconds = 100;


    Runnable r = new Runnable() {   
        public void run() {   
            try {   
                downloadAudioIncrement(mediaUrl);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Unable to initialize the MediaPlayer for fileUrl=" + mediaUrl, e);
                return;
            }   
        }   
    };   
    new Thread(r).start();
}

/**  
 * Download the url stream to a temporary location and then call the setDataSource  
 * for that local file
 */  
@SuppressWarnings({ "resource", "unused" })
public void downloadAudioIncrement(String mediaUrl) throws IOException {

    URLConnection cn = new URL(mediaUrl).openConnection();   
    cn.connect();   
    InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();
    if (stream == null) {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Unable to create InputStream for mediaUrl:" + mediaUrl);
    }

    ///////////////////save sdcard///////////////
    File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/punya");

    if(!direct.exists()) {
        if(direct.mkdir()); //directory is created;
    }

    String[] files=mediaUrl.split("/");

    String fileName=files[files.length-1];
    fileName = fileName.replace(".m4a", ".rdo");


    //create a new file, to save the downloaded file 

    File file = new File(direct,fileName);

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

    ///////////////////end/////////////////

    totalsize=cn.getContentLength();

    //mediaLengthInKb = 10000;

    downloadingMediaFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),fileName);

    if (downloadingMediaFile.exists()) {
        downloadingMediaFile.delete();
    }

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(downloadingMediaFile);   
    byte buf[] = new byte[16384];
    int incrementalBytesRead = 0;
    do {
        numread = stream.read(buf);   
        if (numread <= 0)   
            break;   
        out.write(buf, 0, numread);
        fileOutput.write(buf, 0, numread);
        totalBytesRead += numread;
        incrementalBytesRead += numread;
        totalKbRead = totalBytesRead/1000;
        // pb.setMax(100);
        // pb.setProgress(totalKbRead);

        testMediaBuffer();
        fireDataLoadUpdate();
    } while (validateNotInterrupted());   
    stream.close();
    if (validateNotInterrupted()) {
        fireDataFullyLoaded();
    }
}  

private boolean validateNotInterrupted() {
    if (isInterrupted) {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            //mediaPlayer.release();
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


/**
 * Test whether we need to transfer buffered data to the MediaPlayer.
 * Interacting with MediaPlayer on non-main UI thread can causes crashes to so perform this using a Handler.
 */  
private void  testMediaBuffer() {
    Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (mediaPlayer == null) {
                //  Only create the MediaPlayer once we have the minimum buffered data
                if ( totalKbRead >= INTIAL_KB_BUFFER) {
                    try {
                        startMediaPlayer();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error copying buffered conent.", e);               
                    }
                }
            } else if ( mediaPlayer.getDuration() - mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() <= 1000 ){ 
                //  NOTE:  The media player has stopped at the end so transfer any existing buffered data
                //  We test for < 1second of data because the media player can stop when there is still
                //  a few milliseconds of data left to play
                transferBufferToMediaPlayer();
            }
        }
    };
    handler.post(updater);
}

private void startMediaPlayer() {
    try {   
        //File bufferedFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),"playingMedia" + (counter++) + ".m4a");

        //moveFile(downloadingMediaFile,bufferedFile);

        //  Log.e(getClass().getName(),"Buffered File path: " + bufferedFile.getAbsolutePath());
        //  Log.e(getClass().getName(),"Buffered File length: " + bufferedFile.length()+"");

        mediaPlayer = createMediaPlayer(downloadingMediaFile);

        //mediaPlayer.start();
        startPlayProgressUpdater();         
        //playButton.setEnabled(true);
        playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error initializing the MediaPlayer.", e);
        return;
    }   
}

private MediaPlayer createMediaPlayer(File mediaFile)
        throws IOException {
    MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(
            new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error in MediaPlayer: (" + what +") with extra (" +extra +")" );
                    return false;
                }
            });

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mediaFile);
    mPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
    mPlayer.prepare();
    return mPlayer;
}

/**
 * Transfer buffered data to the MediaPlayer.
 * NOTE: Interacting with a MediaPlayer on a non-main UI thread can cause thread-lock and crashes so 
 * this method should always be called using a Handler.
 */  
private void transferBufferToMediaPlayer() {
    try {

        boolean wasPlaying = mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
        int curPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

        File oldBufferedFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),"playingMedia" + counter + ".m4a");
        File bufferedFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),"playingMedia" + (counter++) + ".m4a");

        bufferedFile.deleteOnExit();   
        moveFile(downloadingMediaFile,bufferedFile);

        //mediaPlayer.pause();
        mediaPlayer.release();

        mediaPlayer = createMediaPlayer(bufferedFile);
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(curPosition);

        boolean atEndOfFile = mediaPlayer.getDuration() - mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() <= 1000;
        if (wasPlaying || atEndOfFile){
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }

        oldBufferedFile.delete();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error updating to newly loaded content.", e);                  
    }
}

private void fireDataLoadUpdate() {
    Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            //float loadProgress = ((float)totalBytesRead/(float)mediaLengthInKb);
            //float per = ((float)numread/mediaLengthInKb) * 100;
            float per = ((float)totalBytesRead/totalsize) * 100;
            textStreamed.setText((totalKbRead + " Kb (" + (int)per + "%)"));
            progressBar.setSecondaryProgress((int)(per));
            pb.setSecondaryProgress((int)(per));

        }
    };
    handler.post(updater);
}

private void fireDataFullyLoaded() {
    Runnable updater = new Runnable() { 
        public void run() {
            transferBufferToMediaPlayer();

            downloadingMediaFile.delete();
            textStreamed.setText(("Download completed" ));

        }
    };
    handler.post(updater);
}

public MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer() {
    return mediaPlayer;
}

public void startPlayProgressUpdater() {
    audiofiletime   =mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    float progress = (((float)mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/ audiofiletime) * 100);
    progressBar.setProgress((int)(progress));
    //pb.setProgress((int)(progress*100));

    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                startPlayProgressUpdater();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(notification,1000);
    }
}    

public void interrupt() {
    playButton.setEnabled(false);
    isInterrupted = true;
    validateNotInterrupted();
}

/**
 *  Move the file in oldLocation to newLocation.
 */
public void moveFile(File   oldLocation, File   newLocation)
        throws IOException {

    if ( oldLocation.exists( )) {
        BufferedInputStream  reader = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream(oldLocation) );
        BufferedOutputStream  writer = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(newLocation, false));
        try {
            byte[]  buff = new byte[5461];
            int numChars;
            while ( (numChars = reader.read(  buff, 0, buff.length ) ) != -1) {
                writer.write( buff, 0, numChars );
            }
        } catch( IOException ex ) {
            throw new IOException("IOException when transferring " + oldLocation.getPath() + " to " + newLocation.getPath());
        } finally {
            try {
                if ( reader != null ){                      
                    writer.close();
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch( IOException ex ){
                Log.e(getClass().getName(),"Error closing files when transferring " + oldLocation.getPath() + " to " + newLocation.getPath() ); 
            }
        }
    } else {
        throw new IOException("Old location does not exist when transferring " + oldLocation.getPath() + " to " + newLocation.getPath() );
    }
}
}
```