# Android MediaPlayer error: MediaPlayer error(1, -2147483648) on Stream from internet

Tags: android, stream, mp3, media-player

I'm trying to stream audio from a URL. The code works fine with other URLs, but in one of those it fails in the `OnPrepared` method, returning this error code: (1, -2147483648). I've read some people saying it's because of permissions, but it's a remote file, so I can't set permissions. I've tried the URL with other apps like VLC and iTunes, and it's working fine. My code is here:

```
private void prepareradio() {
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setAudioStreamType(MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    try {
        player.setDataSource(url);

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    player.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener(){
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"An error happened while preparing radio",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            prepareradio();
            playe.setEnabled(true);
            hidenot();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Which stream? Where is the logcat?

Comment: The stream is this: http://online.radiodifusion.net:8048/ and the logcat only shows twice: MediaPlayer error (1, -2147483648)

Comment: Exactly this 2 lines: E/MediaPlayer(12263): error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer(12263): Error (1,-2147483648) @Bo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are testing on devices earlier than Android 3.1 you might not be able to play AACP (as seen on the info page for your stream (AAC+) streams.

Info page for your stream:
[image]

In order to find out what streams you can play on your targeted device check official docs:    http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html

If you are looking how to handle aacp checkout following:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8833346/200272

Comment: I've tried with another project under 4.0 SDK but doesn't work either, so, I will try with those libraries, I hope it works, thanks @Bo.

Comment: Do not forget that if you find solution to your problem or one of answers fixes your problem vote for the correct answers.

Answer (score 3):

I was also getting the same error on Froyo & Gingerbread. In higher Androids the same video played well. Finally after a lot of research, tried changing the Https Url to Http Url
& Bingo. It resolved my issue. I was using amazon S3 server so that simply replacing the "https" in url with "http" was sufficient.

```
  videoUrl= videoUrl.replaceFirst("https", "http");
```

PS: For supporting older versions if you are using H.264 make sure videos are Baseline encoded.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, this stream is not supported by mediaPlayer. Android supports AAC LC/LTP but your stream is aacp. I think this may be the root cause of your problem.