# MediaPlayer onPrepared not fired

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I've got a little problem with MediaPlayer.
Problem appears on Android 4.0.3 - 4.0.4.
Whats happening is that my onPrepare() method is not fired at all on those two versions.
Tested on 4.3 and 4.4 and no problem at all.

I have no idea what might be the reason for it to not work. So any ideas, thoughts etc are welcome.

PLAY CODE:

```
       try {
            if (!player.isPlaying()) {
                player.reset();
                player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                player.setOnCompletionListener(mFragment);
                player.setDataSource(String.valueOf(tmpUri));
                player.prepareAsync();
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

start() is in on prepare method.

Logcat error:

```
  ERROR/MediaPlayer(10830): Error (1,-2147483648)
  ERROR/MediaPlayer(10830): mOnErrorListener is null. Failed to   send MEDIA_ERROR message.
```

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795388/android-mediaplayer-error-mediaplayer-error1-2147483648-on-stream-from-inte

Comment: Different problems, my audio files are on device memory while there was problem with streaming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ive found the answer to my problem, so I'm going to share my info.

Anyway, the problem was that on Android 4.0.4 and 4.0.3 when reading mp3 files from
device memory setDataSource() did not read the length of file right.
Which made MediaPlayer go psycho and call Error (1,-2147483648).

Android was giving all files length = 0x7ffffffffffffffL.

Why? I don't know ;)

Fix:

```
 File file = new File(uri);
 long length = file.getTotalSpace()
 FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
 player.setDataSource(is.getFD(), 0l, length);
 player.prepareAsync();
```

That's it! 
Hope it will help someone with similar problem, peace!